# Why does the number of bits in the binary representation of decimal number 16 == 5?

Tags: digital-logic

This question not probably not typical stackoverflow but am not sure where to ask this small question of mine.

**Problem:**

> **Find the number of bits in the binary representation of decimal number 16?**

Now I tried to solve this one using the formula $2^n = 16 \Rightarrow n = **4**$ but the correct answer as suggested by my module is 5. Could anybody explain how ?

---

After reading some answer,(and also I have 10 more mints before I could accept the correct answer)I think this is probably an explanation,that will be consistent to the mathematical formula,

For representing 16 we need to represent 17 symbols (0,16), hence $2^n = 17 \Rightarrow n = **4.08746**$ but as n need to be an integer then $n = 5$

Comment: "the answer seems to be 5"?  What does this mean?  Could anybody explain?

Comment: I suppose you just need to understand that Ceil(log2(num)) gives you the number of bits required to express "num" numbers. Not the number "num". The difference is 1 :P

Comment: How many digits do you need to express the decimal representation of 100?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of how binary works:

```
Bit 1: Add 1
Bit 2: Add 2
Bit 3: Add 4
Bit 4: Add 8
Bit 5: Add 16
```

Thus 16 would be: 10000

Answer (score 2):

With 4 bits, you can represent numbers **from 0 to 15**.

So yes, you need 5 bits to represent 16.

Answer (score 1):

```
Decimal - 16 8 4 2 1
Binary -   1 0 0 0 0
```

So for anything up to decimal 31 you only need 5 bits.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic fencepost error.

As you know, computers like to start counting from 0.

So to represent 16, you need bits 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4 (= floor(log2(16))).

But to actually contain bits 0 to 4, you need 5 bits.